# Does the Fourier transform map $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ into itself?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-spaces

Is the Fourier transform of an integrable function ( in $L^1(-\infty, \infty)$ ) also integrable? Put another way if: $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then is

$$  \hat{f}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i xt} f(t) \, dt \stackrel{?}{\in} L^1(\mathbb{R})$$

It would seem to me perfectly reasonable the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ takes $L^1$ to itself since it is an isometry on $L^2$.

Comment: The answer is no, and you've been given a good concrete counterexample. But it's worth being aware of some other facts. The image of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ under the Fourier transform is contained in the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. If you want the transform to give an endomorphism, you have to restrict to the Schwartz space. See, for example, [these concise notes](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/anman2013/anman2013_ch4.pdf).

Comment: Since the Fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2$, the reasonable conjecture is that it **does not** map $L^1$ into itself. Otherwise interpolation inequalities (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) would have awkard consequences.

Comment: @symplectomorphic the functions I am dealing with may not live in [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).  The counter example is indeed a perfect fit!  I do like the how the integral is written out here, rather than in the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: if $f(x)=\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$, then
$$ \hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\;dx=\int_{-1}^1e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\;dx=2\frac{\sin(2\pi \xi)}{2\pi \xi}$$
if $\xi\neq 0$, and $\hat{f}(0)=2$.

One can show that the function $g(y)=\frac{\sin y}{y}$ is not absolutely integrable on $(0,\infty)$ (although interestingly the improper Riemann integral exists, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)) hence $\hat{f}$ is not in $L^1$.

Comment: is that the characteristic function of the interval?

Comment: Yes, $\chi_{E}(x)=1$ if $x\in E$, and $\chi_E(x)=0$ otherwise.